# how to remove single quotes inside BETWEEN condition cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I m trying to separated single quote from the values inside BETWEEN condition in cakephp 2 but it always gets values with single quotes like BETWEEN '2' and '34' .
here is my code:

```
$ref_no1 = $this->request->data['Lead']['ref_no1'];
$ref_no2 = $this->request->data['Lead']['ref_no2'];

$customerHo = $this-> Customer -> find('all',array(
'order' => array('Customer.customer_name' => 'asc'),
'joins'=>array( 
array('table'=>'leads','alias'=>'Lead','type'=>'LEFT','foreignKey'=>false,'conditions'=>array('Customer.customer_id = Lead.customer_id')),
),
'fields'=>'Customer.*,Lead.*',
'conditions' => array(
'Customer.status' => 'active','Customer.customer_id Like'=>'S%',
'Customer.company_id'=>$company_id,
'AND' => array(
array('Lead.ref_no BETWEEN ? and ?' => array($ref_no1,$ref_no2) ),
),
)));
```

I am getting output like :

```
SELECT `Customer`.*, `Lead`.*
FROM `customers` AS `Customer`
LEFT JOIN `timezip_db_demo`.`leads` AS `Lead` ON (`Customer`.`customer_id` = `Lead`.`customer_id`)
WHERE  `Customer`.`customer_id` Like 'S%' AND
`Lead`.`ref_no` BETWEEN '2' and '34' 
ORDER BY `Customer`.`customer_name` asc
```

Expected output :

```
SELECT `Customer`.*, `Lead`.* 
FROM `customers` AS `Customer`  
LEFT JOIN `timezip_db_demo`.`leads` AS `Lead` ON (`Customer`.`customer_id` = `Lead`.`customer_id`)
WHERE  `Customer`.`customer_id` Like 'S%' AND 
`Lead`.`ref_no` BETWEEN 2 and 34 
ORDER BY `Customer`.`customer_name` asc
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you just do it like this? I didn't test this code yet.

```
$ref_no1 = $this->request->data['Lead']['ref_no1'];
$ref_no2 = $this->request->data['Lead']['ref_no2'];

$customerHo = $this-> Customer -> find('all',array(
'order' => array('Customer.customer_name' => 'asc'),
'joins'=>array( 
array('table'=>'leads','alias'=>'Lead','type'=>'LEFT','foreignKey'=>false,'conditions'=>array('Customer.customer_id = Lead.customer_id')),
),
'fields'=>'Customer.*,Lead.*',
'conditions' => array(
'Customer.status' => 'active','Customer.customer_id Like'=>'S%',
'Customer.company_id'=>$company_id,
'AND' => array(
array('Lead.ref_no BETWEEN' . $ref_no1 . 'and' . $ref_no2 ),
),
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert that string into integer, i hope it will work

```
 array((int)$ref_no1,(int)$ref_no2)
```